# Prove f(x) > 0 for all x > 0

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

> Let $f\colon\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function satisfying
>
> 1. $f(0) = 0$
> 2. $f'(x) > f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.
>
> Prove that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.
>
> I considered $f'(0) > f(0) = 0$
> Let f(x) < 0 for all x > 0
> How do I apply indeterminate property and Rolle's theorem to this?

Comment: Solve a differential equation?

Comment: I took the time to format your post, please do so yourself and add your thoughts

Comment: Writing "for all x belong to R" makes no sense. Rather than awkwardly trying to indicate symbols without using them, just say what you actually mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/248076 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1576874.

Comment: Solved by proving Supremum = infinity

Answer (score 4):

Hint: consider the function $g(x) = e^{-x} f(x)$.

Comment: Special case not allowed

Comment: @Singh.  This is not a special case.  Answer is constructing a new function from your given $f$.  Information from $g$ might tell you something about $f$.

Comment: I don't understand how to proceed

Comment: @Singh have you done anything to make you think you should be able to proceed from this hint?

Comment: Consider f(x) < 0 for x > 0

Comment: f'(x) by Rolle should be in interval [0,x]

Comment: Look at $g'(x)=e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))$, how does it helps you?

Comment: Solved by proving Supremum = infinity

Comment: @Singh Huh? If $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ then $\sup_{x>0}f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: If supremum is infinity, then since f(x) is increasing function, therefore, f(x) > 0 for x > 0

Comment: @Singh The only thing you need to prove is that $f(x)$ is increasing, if it's increasing then $f(x)>f(0)=0$.

Comment: It can be solved by proving f(x) > 0 on an interval (0,m) and then taking m as supremum and proving it equal to infinity